Python Discord Music Bot: Playing next song while current song is playing
I've been working on a discord bot for me and my friends and I got it working 90% of the time. I noticed that, on some occasions the bot will be playing a song and it will stop playing the song and just move to the next song. I'm not sure what is causing this directly, but my assumption is that it's because of how I am handling my "play" command and the "play_next" command as well.
I've tried basically everything that I could think of (re-arrange the code, change functionality, etc.). I am not too skilled at Python so my expertise is limited in this field
Here are the two commands:
@client.command(name="p")
async def play(ctx, *, search_query: str):
        global bot_disconnect
        try:
        # Only start a song if the user trying to play a song is in a voice channel
            if ctx.author.voice:
                voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
                voice_client = await voice_channel.connect() # Find who played the song and have the bot enter that channel
                voice_clients[voice_client.guild.id] = voice_client
            else:
                await ctx.channel.send("Get in a voice channel")
                return
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        try:
            if is_youtube_url(search_query):
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Let's the bot multi-task (Similar behavior to interrupts in C/C++)
                data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(search_query, download = False))
                video_url = data["webpage_url"] # Save the youtube video URL to variable
                song_url = data["url"] # Save the extracted URL to a variable
                title = data["title"]
            else:
                url = f"ytsearch:{search_query}"
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Let's the bot multi-task (Similar behavior to interrupts in C/C++)
                data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download = False)) 
                entry = data['entries'][0]
                video_url = entry["webpage_url"] # Save the youtube video URL to variable
                song_url = entry["url"] # Save the extracted URL to a variable
                title = entry["title"]

            if ctx.guild.id in voice_clients and voice_clients[ctx.guild.id].is_playing():
                await queue(ctx, search_query = video_url, title = title)
            else:
                player = discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(song_url, **ffmpeg_options) # THIS IS WHAT PLAYS THE ACTUAL SONG!!!!!!
                await ctx.channel.send(f"Now Playing: {video_url} \n[DOWNLOAD LINK HERE]({song_url})") # Send the video URL to discord channel and include a download link as well
                bot_disconnect = False
                voice_clients[ctx.guild.id].play(player, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(play_next(ctx), client.loop))
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)



async def play_next(ctx):
    if len(queues) != 0 and queues.get(ctx.guild.id):         
        search_query = queues[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)[0] # Pull the URL from the next index
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() # Let's the bot multi-task (Similar behavior to interrupts in C/C++)
        print(f"{search_query}")
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(search_query, download = False))
        player = discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(data["url"], **ffmpeg_options)
        voice_client = voice_clients[ctx.guild.id]
        voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(play_next(ctx), client.loop))
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Now Playing: {data['webpage_url']} \n[DOWNLOAD LINK HERE]({data['url']})") # Send the video URL to discord channel and include a download link as well
    else:
        await ctx.send("No songs in queue")

I can also link the full code if we want to see the entire thing.
